# Do religious moral systems contain moral relativism?

Tags: ethics, relativism

The phrase "moral relativism" has always felt to me like something that one can find in non religious moral systems (western humanistic state laws), but I am not sure if it is really non existent in religious moral systems, especially Abrahamic ones such as Judaism, Christianity, Islam (and possibly also Gnosticism).

Comment: If you mean *monotheistic* religions like Judaism, Christianity and Islam (Gnosticism is a variant of Christianity) then there is no room for moral relativism there. There is only one objective right morality, namely the one established by the one true God.

Comment: @Conifold a big yes, I prefer to say Abrahamic rather than "monotheistic" not to trigger comments like "Tengrism, Great spirit of Navajo etc. are also monotheistic"; about Gnosticism, considering the history of the Mandeans, I think this is controversial but that's just my opinion.

Comment: What I primarily ought to know is that okay, if indeed Abrahamic religions are not at all relativistic, is western secular humanism really just a parallel term to "relativism" or might there be relativism that doesn't have anything to do with western secular humanism?

Comment: Western secular humanism need not be morally relativistic, see [moral realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-realism/), and moral relativism much predates humanism, [Protagoras](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-relativism/#HisBac) is considered an early proponent. If you are looking for non-Western versions [Taoism](https://www.ligonier.org/learn/articles/philosophical-taoism) is sometimes interpreted that way.

Comment: One could also say that, while abrahamic religions **claim** to be morally absolute, they are in fact just as relativist as any value system. The word of God is known through the scriptures, which were written, selected and compiled by people. Then, they require interpretation and prioritization (because nobody can manage all the rules, some are set to be more important than others), which just tend to reflect the cultural bias of the interpreter more than often. That's why people who claim to get their morals from the same "absolute" source happen to disagree so much they kill each other.

Comment: @armand's comment is the only one that matters. Just look at the actual history of any religion. Even their so-called sacred scriptures were retroactively edited by their 'proponents' due to political reasons. For example, compare Samaritan and Judaistic Torah, and look up the history of the Johannine interpolation, the Nicene creed, and so on. Note also that most Abrahamic religions consider any failure to accept their theological beliefs as moral sin. How can that ever be not relative?